# Is it possible to use Signal on a desktop without using Android or iPhone?

Tags: sms, signal-app

I use a simple Nokia phone with a key pad (I don't want a smart phone because I want to enjoy my time away from a computer). This simple phone can receive sms.

Is it possible to link my phone to the signal software without Android or iPhone? The site mentions that it should be possible to register using SMS:

support.signal.org: [Register a phone number](https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/articles/360007318691-Register-a-phone-number) says:

> The number must be able to receive an SMS or phone call.

But I don't see the option to enter a phone number in the desktop application.

[image]

Comment: I guess you could use an Android emulator, but you'd still need it to be able to receive SMS on that number.

Comment: Yes I am able to receive sms on that number.

Comment: you may want to share your input (on a feature request): https://community.signalusers.org/t/remove-the-need-for-a-mobile-phone/1543

Answer (score 3):

It is possible using https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli.

Here is a step-by-step guide: https://ctrl.alt.coop/en/post/signal-without-a-smartphone/

In a nutshell:

```sh
signal-cli -u YOUR_NUMBER register
# get SMS with verification code
signal-cli -u YOUR_NUMBER verify VERIFICATIONCODE
# start Signal Desktop and decode the QR code
signal-cli -u YOUR_NUMBER addDevice --uri "tsdevice:/?uuid..."
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible according to github issue [#551 Allow registration from the desktop application](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues/551):

> moxie0 commented on Dec 27, 2015
>
> > Thanks but we're not going to do this
>
> @moxie0 closed this on Dec 27, 2015

Github user @moxie0 was the main developer of the Signal-Android app until 2018 according to [this list of contributors](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/graphs/contributors).

See also wikipedia [Signal_(software)#Desktop-specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(software)#Desktop-specific):

> "Setting up Signal's desktop app requires that the user first install Signal on an Android or iOS based smartphone with an Internet connection."
> [...]
> " As of March 2019, Signal's desktop app does not include support for voice or video calling."

Related and interesting quote from that [wikipedia article on signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(software)):

> "Feb 2018 [Moxie Marlinspike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moxie_Marlinspike) and [Brian Acton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Acton) launch the Signal Foundation with an initial $50 million in funding from Acton, who had left WhatsApp's parent company Facebook in September 2017."